Is it worthwhile to put small grants for cloud credits on a CV?
I applied and got a small grant of $5000 to use cloud credits on Google Cloud as a PI for my lab:
https://edu.google.com/intl/ALL_us/programs/credits/research/?modal_active=none
Is it worthwhile at all to even put these small grants in my CV?

Depends on what else could fill the space, and what the CV will be used for.

It's just a regular academic CV, there's no limits to space. What I'm trying to determine is if people put this sort of thing in CVs at all.

Just a quick note that if you are in the US and apply for federal funding, this would be considered in kind support, and should be disclosed in your grant applications.  You should make sure you disclose this in your documents as appropriate.

Still, if you are a professor at an R1 school in the US with million-dollar grants, you might not bother. If you are a professor at a small liberal arts college with minimal grant funding (if any at all), then it could well be important. Academic CVs are still all about selling you to the next job application committee or grant funding agency review committee.

Yes. Applying for grants is one of the bread and butter types of work that academics do. For this reason, any successful grant application, even with a relatively small monetary value, would be great to put on your CV. I have seen tenured professors mention such things in their CVs. (Not that it’s necessary a very impressive achievement for someone at that career stage, but it’s at least worth mentioning like many other things.)
Of course, everything’s relative. If you won the Nobel Prize, then the $5K cloud credits are irrelevant, and would just clutter up your CV.

Instead of looking only at the absolute numbers ($ brought in), you could also consider different sources of funding. While 5k may drown in the face of an R01, getting money from companies through whatever means as well as from other agencies/foundations on different topics speaks to your versatility and agility as a scientist. From that perspective I'd put it in (and at least keep an academic master CV with all these details). You can always delete later and/or as you see fit depending on the circumstances and how the rest of your CV and future career aspirations develop.

I'm not a PI, but as a grad student I secured Cloud Credits as Collaborative Grant and it is on my resume. My peers often mention that when they introduce me to people in those circles. So it might not matter a lot in terms of the amount of funding, but definitely has impacts when networking in related communities.
